# Form Theme / Template in Phalcon

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, phalcon, volt

Having ditched Symfony in favor of Phalcon I have stumbled across a problem regarding form templates.

I understand for example a field is rendered in this way:

```
{{ text_field("name", "size" : 30) }}

{{ submit_button("Save") }}
```

and if I wanted to apply a class to this field it would look like:

```
{{ text_field("name", "size" : 30, "class" : "classForField") }}

{{ submit_button("Save", "class" : "btn btn-success") }}
```

However doing this for the 100's of fields, buttons etc in my app would be a massive hassle, especially if I decided for some reason to change the Css clas for just 'text_fields' for example.

In Symfony you would define a basic template for all fields in a template file which in turn would be used by all forms unless overridden.

I've looked through many of the sample projects, and through the documentation but I can't find such a feature in Phalcon. I'm hoping this is just me looking for the wrong terminology could someone point me in the right direction please.

Specifically I want to apply Bootstrap classes to my elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to use [Phalcon\Forms](http://docs.phalconphp.com/pl/latest/reference/forms.html).

You can use `Form` objects to declare, generate and than validate you forms. Based to [manual example](http://docs.phalconphp.com/pl/latest/reference/forms.html#initializing-forms) you can add attributes to fields during `Form::add` like this:

```
$this->add(new Text("name", array(
    'maxlength' => 30,
    'placeholder' => 'Type your name',
    'class' => 'css classes'
)));
```

It takes some time to learn manipulating those forms, especially when it goes to sanitization+validation. Anyway I would recommend to make your  extensions for al fields in `\Phalcon\Forms\Element\*`, where you can declare your default css, being able to adjust them during both element creation in Form, and later during Volt template.

Comment: I think essentially my issue was a lack of understanding as far as namespaces went. Done a bit of research now. Will try your method tonight after work hopefully. Accepted but I may need to ask you a question later.